# Hide FreeBSD swap partition in XFCE or KDE file manager

Tags: freebsd, kde, xfce, thunar, dolphin

I have just installed a FreeBSD 11.1-RELEASE (amd64) desktop system following [the Cooltrainer guide](https://cooltrainer.org/a-freebsd-desktop-howto/).

For some reason, both XFCE's Thunar and KDE's Dolphin file managers both show an 8 GB device in the devices list (in the panel at the left of the file manager, which, for example, also shows the CD-ROM drive). This device is most likely my swap partition (Thunar does not show the device's name, but Dolphin does show it to be my swap partition `/dev/ada0p2`). Does anyone know how I can prevent the `/dev/ada0p2` swap partition from showing up as a device in the file manager?

My hard disk is partitioned as follows:

```
% gpart show
=>       40  625142368  ada0  GPT  (298G)
         40       1024     1  freebsd-boot  (512K)
       1064        984        - free -  (492K)
       2048   16777216     2  freebsd-swap  (8.0G)
   16779264  608362496     3  freebsd-zfs  (290G)
  625141760        648        - free -  (324K)
```

My `/etc/fstab` is as follows:

```
% cat /etc/fstab
# Device                Mountpoint      FStype  Options         Dump    Pass#
/dev/ada0p2             none            swap    sw              0       0
proc                    /proc           procfs  rw              0       0
fdesc                   /dev/fd         fdescfs rw,auto,late    0       0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inspired by [this post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1060256&p=6677262#post6677262) on the Ubuntu forums, I found out the culprit was the [Hardware Abstraction Layer](https://www.freebsd.org/gnome/docs/halfaq.html).

I ignored the device in question by creating the following file:

```
/usr/local/share/hal/fdi/preprobe/20thirdparty/10-ignore-swap.fdi
```

with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<deviceinfo version="0.2">
  <device>
    <match key="block.device" string="/dev/ada0p2">
      <merge key="info.ignore" type="bool">true</merge>
    </match>
  </device>
</deviceinfo>
```

This causes the device to be ignored by the HAL, and to no longer show up in the XFCE or KDE file managers.